# Matlab: Format the decimals in contour labels

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, contour

I want to cut the number of decimals in the following contour plot. I do:

```
[cc,hh] = contour(X,Y,Z,levels,'LineColor','k');hold on
texth = clabel(cc,hh,'FontSize',8);
```

which gets me the first contour with long labels. Then in order to cut the decimals I do:

```
for i = 1:size(texth); textstr=get(texth(i),'String'); textnum=str2double(textstr); textstrnew=sprintf('%0.0f', textnum) ; set(texth(i),'String',textstrnew); end
```

And this gives the second plot. As you see, there is a wide gap between the label and the contour lines which looks awful. Any ideas how to solve this?

[image]

Comment: Do you need the contours to have that specific values? because you could just create the contours in the integer values instead!

Comment: I tried to round the decimals in the cc vector, but it didn't work! I mean the Z matrix doesn't have integers....

Comment: Try replacing `levels` with `round(levels)` when you create the plot.

Comment: @David Most likely he is using levels as a integer.

Comment: It depends whether `levels` is the number of levels or a vector with the contour levels. @OliverAmundsen this is why it's always good to give code that runs when you ask questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of modifying the result, create a contour plot with the levels you want, so you don't need to cheat the data.

Define levels as e.g. `levels=997:1010`

and then

```
contour(X,Y,Z,levels,'LineColor','k','ShowText','on');
```

Will create a contour plot with the text included and the levels being specifically the ones in the variable `levels`, in this case 997,998,999,...,1009,1010

If, as @David suggests, your levels variable already is a vector, then replace it by `round(levels)` as himself suggested.